# Porque no me deja agregar mas objetos en un Select con react-select?

Tags: reactjs, react-select

Tengo un problema con `react-select`, cuando agrego un objeto y luego intento agregar otro me sale lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y se supone que en cuanto al codigo yo le tengo activado desde el codigo:

```
<Select
       id="responsables"
       name="responsables"
       isMulti
       defaultValue={props.outFields.responsables}
       options={responsable}
       onChange={(e) => props.onInputChange({ target: { name:'responsables', value: e } })}
       className="basic-multi-select"
       classNamePrefix="select"/>
```

segun tengo entendido esta seria la forma 'correcta' de hacerlo usando esta libreria verdad?, de no ser asi que es lo que puede estar pasando si la informacion la esta guardado:

```
responsable:[{label:'z'}]
```

estoy ignorando algo? o que podria ser?

[Editado]:

Lo que hay en props, en `onInputChange()` es lo siguiente:

```
const onInputChange = (evt) => {
   setFields({
     ...fields,
     [evt.target.name]: evt.target.value
   })
   setIsCancel(true)
}
```

En donde `fields` esta la informacion de los responsables donde hay aun mas informacion

```
...
fechaAdquisicion: '2017-05-24',
fechaUltimoMovimiento: '2017-05-24',
responsables:[],
donador: '',
idTelar: '',
...

axios.get('/responsable').then(resp => {
    setResponsable(resp.data.map(dat => ({ label: dat.nombre })))
})
```

Esto seria lo que esta en props, no se si se necesita algo mas?

Comment: Haz una prueba. Remueve todo lo referente al `onChange`  del select y prueba si te funciona. Sospecho que la función `props.onInputChange` está modificando el arreglo de opciones `responsable` y por ello ese comportamiento.

Comment: No puedes modificar tu arreglo de opciones (en este caso `responsable`). Si lo modificas se modifica en la vista. Cuando seleccionas algo, estás borrando todo lo demás y dejando solo la seleccionada, claro que no te va a mostrar nada más.

Comment: Intente quitar on change pero aun asi no solo me deja agregar uno, en teoria onInputChange afecta unicamente a props.outFields.responsables y no tendria nada que ver con responsable

Comment: Otra cosa tambien es que si inicializo responsables con valores que existen en options y son mas de un elemento, este si lo detecta y e deja borrarlo, el problema es que no me deja agregar mas

Comment: Agrega tu logica de manejo del componente. Los estados, lo que le pasas por props, etc. En el código que adjuntas no está para nada contenido el problema que planteas y es imposible reproducirlo. Yo copie y cree tu codigo en un proyecto de react pasandole unos options como supongo yo que lo estas pasando y funciona perfectamente.